# Пишу веб-приложение на Slim Framework. Пытаюсь пользоваться автозагрузкой классов через composer, но класс не подгружается, не знаю уже что делать

Tags: php, классы, composer, slim, slim4

Мне нужно в файл index.php загрузить класс Reg, который находится в файле register_class.php, который в свою очередь лежит в директории src

Вот этот файл:
[image: register_class.php]

Вот файл composer.json:

[image: composer.json]

А вот неполный файл index.php:
[image: index.php]

Когда я инициализирую объект класса Reg, у меня на странице возникает ошибка http error 500. Не знаю, что делать, прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы подключаете автозагрузку по стандарту PSR4, а именуете файлы не по стандарту.

если у Вас загрузка неймспейса `MyClasses` настроена на диреторию `src`, то класс `MyClasses\Reg` нужно положить в файл `src/Reg.php` (регистр ВАЖЕН). Класс `MyClasses\Very\Deep\Obj` - в файл `src/Very/Deep/Obj.php` и т.д.